# Bookmark useful questions

Tags: support

Is there a feature to bookmark the questions/answers one finds particularly useful for future reference?

Comment: You mean beyond the fav star? Why?

Comment: did't noticed that functionality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Star the question, and you'll find it listed under the "**favorites**" tab of your profile for the site

[image]